# In the below java code, how can I ask the user to input how many shots they would like in each of their coffee cups (Given they order more than 1)?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.scanner;

public class CoffeeBot {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Hello, what's your name?");
    String name = scanner.nextline();
    System.out.println("Would you like to order some coffee, "+name+(y/n)?")
    String response = scanner.nextline()
    {
     if response = y
     System.out.println("Great! Lets get started.")
     System.out.println("There are 6 coffee cups in stock and each costs $2.00.");
        System.out.println("There are 8 coffee shot in stock and each costs $1.00.");
        System.out.println("How many cups of coffee would you like?");
        int cups;
        cups = keyboard.nextInt();
        {
            if cups = 0;
            System.out.println("No cups, no coffee. Goodbye.");
            System.exit();

            if cups < 0;
            System.out.println("Does not compute. System terminating.");
            System.exit();

            if cups > 6;
            System.out.println("Not enough stock. Come back later.");
            System.exit();
        }
        System.out.println("How many coffee shots in cup 1?");
        int shots;
        shots = keyboard.nextInt();
```

For instance If the user orders 2 cups, I am supposed to ask the user how many shots they want in each of the cups i.e. in cup1 and cup2. Can someone please suggest how I can construct a code for this action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code have lots of mistakes. So i corrected the code as this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CoffeeBot {

static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {


    System.out.println("Hello, what's your name?");
    String name = keyboard.next();
    System.out.println("Would you like to order some coffee, "+name+"(y/n)?");
    String response = keyboard.next();
    {
     if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("y")){
     System.out.println("Great! Lets get started.");
     System.out.println("There are 6 coffee cups in stock and each costs $2.00.");
        System.out.println("There are 8 coffee shot in stock and each costs $1.00.");
        System.out.println("How many cups of coffee would you like?");
        int cups;
        cups = keyboard.nextInt();

        {
            if (cups == 0){
            System.out.println("No cups, no coffee. Goodbye.");

            }

            if (cups < 0){
            System.out.println("Does not compute. System terminating.");
            }

            if (cups > 6){
            System.out.println("Not enough stock. Come back later.");
            }
        }
        shots(cups); //This methods calls the shots static class

}

    }
}
public static int[] shots(int num){
    int[] shots = new int[num];
    for(int i = 0; i<num;i++){
    System.out.println("How many coffee shots in cup "+(i+1)+" ?");
    shots[i] = keyboard.nextInt();  
    }
    return shots;
}
}
```

What I have done here is created a separate static class to do you requirement. `shots(cups);` will call the function.

The function will take and integer value as an parameter. This is to initiate an array. The array will hold the no of shots each cup needs.

```
public static int[] shots(int num){
        int[] shots = new int[num];
        for(int i = 0; i<num;i++){
        System.out.println("How many coffee shots in cup "+(i+1)+" ?");
        shots[i] = keyboard.nextInt();  
        }
        return shots;
    }
```

this method will loop through no of cups times to ask the user how many shots needed and placed it in an array. Finally the array will be returned to the place where method called. you can do what ever you wanted.